# Magento _core_url_rewrite table is 3.1Gib

Tags: mysql, database, magento

I have noticed that _core_url_rewrite table is 3.1Gib and was wondering if this is normal, to me it seems odd.

Could this be a reason for slow page loads? If so, how could I have this issue fixed.

Thank you all in advance.